# Why float objects in Python doesn't have denominator attribute, while int does?

Tags: python, types, floating-point, int

While I was messing around with Python,

```
>>> [attr for attr in dir(1) if not attr.startswith('_')]
['bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
>>> [attr for attr in dir(1.1) if not attr.startswith('_')]
['as_integer_ratio', 'conjugate', 'fromhex', 'hex', 'imag', 'is_integer', 'real']
```

Although I understand that 'conjugate', 'imag', and 'real' are there for the sake of compatibility with complex type, I can't understand why 'numerator' and 'denominator' exists for int only, and doesn't for a float.

Any explanation for that ?

Comment: What would you expect `math.pi.denominator` to return?

Comment: I'd say 7, but after Wikipedia-ing I understood that pi is irrational number and doesn't exactly equal 22/7 the rational version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely because floats are somewhat lossy - they can not perfectly represent every value. Consider this example:

```
>>> 1.0/5.0
0.20000000000000001
```

If you wanted the access the denominator of `1.0/5.0` python would have to return `18014398509481984` (`20000000000000001/100000000000000000 == 3602879701896397/18014398509481984`). The loss of precision will cause python to have no choice but to return crazy values, so the designers chose not to implement the function.

Comment: You mean `3602879701896397/18014398509481984`.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the number class hierarchy: [Python numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html)

`numbers.Integral` is a sub class of `numbers.Rational`

It's numbers.Rational that adds the numerator and denominator members.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `int` is a subclass of `rational`, and `float` is not. Since `rational` has a denominator attribute, `int` inherited it.

You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html)